# IRC(Twitch chat) Text-to-speech

Tags: c, vb.net, text-to-speech, irc, twitch

Hey everyone I'm looking for a way to code a program/bot in VB that would read my chat, but only if a command is used

*For example: "!tts Hello"*

And It would read it using TTS and show it on screen

*$USERNAME$ !tts: Hello*

Now the thing I don't know how to set up is the program reading the chat, printing it on screen I believe is the easy part.

Also if it's possible to add an option to select to which audio output it will go.

Comment: You can use the twitch api to interact with the twitch chat https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc

Answer (score 0):

You need to study more coding...

Im not a master at it myself. but i would make a boolean that could be true if the first letter in a chatline is a "!". And then a command that would add that line to a text-to-speech module

Comment: Of course, I mean we learn every day and I am learning more every day! Also that was my first thought, to use boolean for "!tts" since if its only "!" it will have conflict with normal chat bot, thanks for the quick answer, but still my question is how to make the TTS module

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by conflict with the chatbot

Comment: Well since chat bots like Nightbot use ! to execute commands like !uptime which would give: $channel$ has been live for $uptime$ 
That would mean that TTS would then read any "!" command even the one above.